# Sequelize create includes eager loaded values

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am working on a project using:

- Node.js `v20.10.0`
- npm `v10.2.3`
- sequelize `v6.25.3`
- sequelize-typescript `v2.1.6`

I have defined the models using `sequelize-typescript` library. One of the models is:

```js
@Table({ tableName: 'testAttemptDate' })
export default class TestAttemptDate extends Model {
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  declare id: number;

  // Foreign key
  @AllowNull(false)
  @ForeignKey(() => TestAttemptHistory)
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  declare testAttemptHistoryId: number;

  @UpdatedAt
  declare updatedAt: Date;

  @CreatedAt
  declare createdAt: Date;

  // Associations
  @HasMany(() => FinalItemAnswer, {
    foreignKey: 'testAttemptDateId',
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  })
  declare finalItemAnswers: ReturnType<() => FinalItemAnswer[]>;

  @BelongsTo(() => TestAttemptHistory)
  declare testAttemptHistory: ReturnType<() => TestAttemptHistory>;
}
```

It has a foreign key while the rest of its fields should be automatically created during `.create` function.

Followingly, this is the function that should create a `TestAttemptDate` entry:

```js
/**
 * Track date of a test attempt
 * @param {number} testAttemptHistoryId
 */
export async function createTestAttemptDate(
  testAttemptHistoryId: number,
): Promise<ITestAttemptDate> {
  return TestAttemptDate.create({ testAttemptHistoryId });
}
```

However, this function fails with the following error message:

```json
 {
    "message": {
        "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
        "parent": {
            "length": 111,
            "name": "error",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "code": "42703",
            "position": "173",
            "file": "parse_relation.c",
            "line": "3563",
            "routine": "errorMissingColumn",
            "sql": "INSERT INTO \"testAttemptDate\" (\"id\",\"testAttemptHistoryId\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3) RETURNING \"id\",\"testAttemptHistoryId\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\",\"activityId\",\"itemId\";",
            "parameters": [
                3,
                "2024-02-02 14:17:53.108 +00:00",
                "2024-02-02 14:17:53.108 +00:00"
            ]
        },
    }
}
```

Based on the `sql` query mentioned in the above error message in the `RETURNING` part it tries to return `activityId` and `itemId` which are not fields of `TestAttemptDate` but fields of the model associated with the `TestAttemptDate`.

What can cause this error?

PS: this is part of an API call and the error returned by the server is `{"message":"column \"activityId\" does not exist"}`.

Comment: Did you try to remove/comment associations in `TestAttemptDate` and run the query again? What SQL will be generated?